# How to host microservice based static Angular build projects to AWS S3 and manage the routing correctly?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, routes, aws-lambda-edge

Currently what is happening is
we have 7 to 10 different Angular microservices for our Company's SAAS platform, previously which was running in EC2 engine and Nginx managed the routing but the cost of EC2 is very high, so I am trying to migrate the website into a static website in S3, although I am have successfully migrated the website in S3 and connected to CloudFront but facing routing issues as previously it was managed by Nginx and Angular's own routing, but now it has been converted into S3 folder based routing

**Previously it was like**

```
/global-dashboard/compliance_dashboard
```

But as ***global-dashboard*** is a microservice so if I call the entire URL of

```
/global-dashboard/compliance_dashboard
```

it is not working it is redirecting to /global-dashboard  because I put my microservice angular project into the /global-dashboard folder in S3 then it is searching for another folder of

```
/compliance_dashboard
```

But it is not able to find the route as this route is rendered by Angular frontend component based router

Can you please give me any ideas on how to solve these?

**Tried** Lambda@Edge,  Cloudfront origin and behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add cloudfront in your S3 ! S3 only do HTTP on index.html. with cloudfront you will have HTTPS and routing and Security for DDOS.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Obviously, CloudFront is connected to my S3 also tried Lambda@Edge in CloudFront